# Warum gibt es keinen "Vortisch"?

Tags: etymology

Es gibt die *Nachspeise* und die *Vorspeise* vom gleichen Rang.

Zur Nachspeise gibt es dann noch das Synonym *Nachtisch*, aber das Äquivalent *Vortisch* gibt es laut einer groben Google-Suche nur als Familienname.

Yahoo Clever hat eine [passende Frage](https://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070317045027AAC5q8x), aber keine guten Antworten.

1. War *Vortisch* jemals in der Bedeutung *Vorspeise* in verbreitetem Gebrauch?
2. Wie kam es, dass es im Gegensatz zum *Nachtisch* nicht überlebt hat?

Comment: ad 1) Jein, in Gebrauch, aber wohl nicht verbreitet ([DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=26,1746,46)).

Comment: wohlgemerkt gibt es auch keinen *Haupttisch*. Also scheint eher *Nachtisch* eine besondere Etymologie aufzuweisen.

Comment: @chirlu Im Grimm-Wörterbuch habe ich auch gesucht. Das dort zitierte Beispiel klingt mir aber auch eher so, als hätte jemand zum Zwecke des Ausdrucks das Wort *Vortisch* einfach aus dem *Nachtisch* konstruiert. In meinem Herkunftswörterbuch zu Hause ist aber leider noch nicht einmal *Nachtisch* verzeichnet. An sich ist die Herkunft wohl auch relativ klar (vmtl. *nach dem Speisen zu Tische*). Nur hätte da ja auch was zum Vortisch stehen können.

Comment: @Janek ist die Herkunft _so_ klar? Im Yahoo-Thread steht was davon, dass die Nachspeisen auf einem extra Tisch reingerollert wurden, nachdem der Hauptgang durch war. Das ist hier bei uns noch nicht hochgekommen,  aber vielleicht bringt es noch jemand.

Comment: Wer weiß. War eine Vermutung, auch weil es halt im Wörterbuch nicht drin steht.

Comment: Möglicherweise aus dem gleichen Grund, warum es ein "Dessert", aber kein "Sert" gibt?

Comment: Eine wilde Vermutung: Die Vorspeise wird am Esstisch genossen. Die Nachspeise zuweilen "am Kamin". Man ist dann also nicht mehr "bei Tisch".

Comment: Möglicherweise hat man ja in früherer Zeit gar keinen Bedarf für das Wort gehabt - Man kann den Deutschen ja viel nachsagen, aber ausgeprägte Esskultur wie z.B. in Frankreich gehört eher nicht dazu - zumindestens nicht historisch. Da hat man, wenn überhaupt, *Suppe* vorweg gegessen, also reichte das Wort dafür. Fragt man nach einer "typisch deutschen" Vorspeise, fällt einem eben höchstens die Suppe ein

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mit Google [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Vortisch&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVortisch%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CVortisch%3B%2Cc1) kann man die Verbreitung von Worten und Phrasen über die Zeit visualisieren, und dann in den Listen nach Exempeln schauen, was hier dazu führt, dass man nur den Namen Vortisch findet, auch wenn das Wort im Vergleich zu [Vorspeise, Nachspeise und Nachtisch](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Vortisch%2C%20Vorspeise%2C%20Nachtisch%2C%20Nachspeise&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVortisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVorspeise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNachtisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNachspeise%3B%2Cc0) nicht abgehängt wird.

Eine Suche im [Wörterbuchnetz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/startGlobalSearch.tcl?stichwort=Vortisch) fördert nur 2 Treffer zutage, was die Vermutung, der Begriff sei je verbreitet gewesen, in Zweifel zieht.

Vielleicht findet jmd. eine plausible Erklärung, wieso sich der Begriff nicht durchgesetzt hat. In der Regel dürften sich solche Fragen schlecht beantworten lassen, da man dazu i.d.R. große Menschenmengen befragen müsste, die auch noch lange tot sind. Allgemein weist die Sprache oft keine Symmetrie auf. Der zweite Graph zeigt, dass auch die Vorspeise erst in jüngerer Zeit weitere Verbreitung findet - wohl weil ein Nachtisch verbreitet, eine Vorspeise aber selten war.

Es gibt auch Vollmond und Vollpfosten sowie Neumond, jedoch keinen Neupfosten. So ist Sprache.

Comment: Alles richtig, aber: Es gab die deutsche Sprache schon vor Google...

Comment: @tofro: Google NGram ist eine Auswertung auch historischer Bücher und greift bis ins Jahr 1500 zurück. Diei Wörterbücher des Wörterbuchnetzes sind auch alt bis uralt bzw. berücksichtigen alte Quellen. Deine Kritik verstehe ich daher nicht.

Comment: Das war nur begrenzt als Kritik gemeint - NGram kann halt nur die Bücher untersuchen, die auch in digitalisierter Form vorliegen. nGram kann zwar *Hinweise* liefern, aber eine vollständige Abdeckung historischer und vor allem deutscher Bücher dürfte es nicht leisten. Über die anderen Fallstricke an NGram gibt's hier einen netten Artikel: http://www.wired.com/2015/10/pitfalls-of-studying-language-with-google-ngram/ .   Muss also eine Prise Salz dazu.

Comment: @tofro: Eine gute NGram-Kritik, bei der noch fehlt, dass Zeitungen und Magazine m.W. nicht erfasst werden wie natürlich auch nicht private oder geschäftliche Korrespondenz, Bedienungsanleitungen, Beipackzettel usw., und dass der mündliche Sprachgebrauch auch vollkommen fehlt. Das kann man aber schlecht bei jeder Verwendung von NGram wiederholen.

Comment: Das Accept für den bequellten Inzidenznachweis, vielen Dank!

Answer (score 6):

Ich hatte eine Intuition, dass es etwas mit der früher verbreiteten Wendung *nach Tisch* zu tun haben könnte. Mir war nämlich nicht bewusst, dass es auch *vor Tisch* gibt. Der n-gram-Viewer hat mich eines Bessern belehrt. Ergebnis:

Bis ca. 1860 waren *bei Tisch* und *nach Tisch* etwa gleich häufig. In letzter Zeit dominiert allerdings *bei Tisch* (etwa Faktor 6). Daneben ist aber durchaus auch *vor Tisch* gebräuchlich, und zwar mit rund einem Drittel der Häufigkeit von *nach Tisch*.

Eine Suche in älteren deutschen Büchern nach *vor Tisch* und *nach Tisch* hat dann aber doch noch eine Spur ergeben. "Nach Tisch" wird dort typischerweise die Geselligkeit gepflegt, getrunken oder Spazieren gegangen. Der Verzehr von Süßem scheint da ganz gut dazu zu passen. "Vor Tisch" wird ebenfalls Spazieren gegangen, Disziplin unter den Kindern hergestellt, nichts Süßes gegessen (weil es den Appetit verdirbt), und, ganz wichtig, gebetet.

Mir scheint deshalb, dass hier zu Lande, anders als bei den Römern und ihren direkteren kulturellen Nachfahren, der Grundsatz "Erst die Arbeit, dann das Vergnügen" galt: Erst die Moral, dann die Sättigung, dann das Vergnügen. Da bleibt dann, wie auch schon von user unknown vermutet, kein Raum für Vorspeisen. Das deckt sich übrigens auch durchaus mit meinen eigenen Erfahrungen. Im deutschen Sprachraum hab ich außer dem im Restaurant häufig zuerst servierten Beilagensalat selten Vorspeisen erlebt. In Frankreich, Italien und Spanien ist das aber sehr häufig.

Fazit soweit: Ein *Vortisch* wäre im Deutschen wohl eher so etwas wie ein Tischgebet. Das wäre aber eine überflüssige und unpassende Bezeichnung und war deshalb wohl nie üblich.

Eine andere Sichtweise: "Tisch" bezieht sich im Kontext von "vor/bei/nach Tisch" wohl auf das soziale Ereignis, zu dem alle Familienmitglieder versammelt sind. (Das ist der Hauptunterschied zu "Speise" im Kontext der Frage.) "Nach Tisch" bedeutet dann, dass das Ereignis im Prinzip vorbei ist. Wer will, kann schon mal gehen - er verpasst dann aber u.U das Beste (den "Nachtisch"). "Vor Tisch" ist der Zeitraum *bevor* alle versammelt sind. Vor dem für alle obligatorischen Tischgebet wurde aber nichts verzehrt. Selbst wenn es doch mal Vorspeisen gab, wurden sie wohl erst nach dem Tischgebet serviert und waren damit "bei Tisch", nicht "vor Tisch".

Comment: Super Train-of-thought, Danke :-)

Comment: Die Bounty für die ausführliche Argumentation und das offensichtliche Brüten-über-dem-Problem, vielen Dank.